# Rolodex-like iOS App that Vertically Scrolls 

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, scroll

I want to create an app that looks like a Rolodex Card wherein you'll have to scroll vertically in different views and when tapped, will go on full screen view with a close button to return to the previous view in a Rolodex-kind-of-menu. I want it to look similar to the PepperUI iOS control but instead of having it horizontally scroll, I want it scrolled vertically like in the picture below:

[image]

Any idea on how I can implement this kind of app? I'm thinking that this will only have Core Animations involved when scrolling the cards-like view controllers and zooming on a specific view when the user tapped any view in the cards.

Thanks for any input on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest this [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) by NickLockwood. Great Project. You can tweak it the way you want it, believe me. Make it vertical, and look up into its type cause it supports 11 types including like the one you want. Check it out!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to play around with iCarousel but the animations that iCarousel has is different from the one in PepperUI. Thanks though.